# What is the world record for the longest D&D marathon?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, time, session

I have been looking for a while to find the world record for the longest Dungeons and Dragons marathon because me and my friends had a plan to try and attempt to beat it and give the money from the stream (if we get any) to my school's Gaming and Anime Club.

Comment: I am going for a world record and all of the info I have is the answers to this question and that for every hour, you would get a 5 min break from the game thank you for answering my question

Comment: Worth noting that you may want to contact Guiness and make sure they will even consider your record before attempting this. My understanding is that they have gotten rid of many of the records that involve simply doing some activity for the longest period of time.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose The OP doesn't mention Guinness, who are not the sole arbiter of world records.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The record seems to be **209 hours** (= 8 days, 17 hours).

According to the Reddit post [An update to James Wallis' claim about setting a Guinness World Record for the longest D&D game](https://old.reddit.com/r/KotakuInAction/comments/9exp2n/drama_an_update_to_james_wallis_claim_about/), Reddit user JustOneAmongMany asked Guinness about an alleged 1985/6 record. Guinness responded on September 4, 2018 with this message:

> Thank you for contacting Guinness World Records.
>
> A search of our database shows two Dungeons & Dragons endurance
> records from that general time period:
>
> From June 30th through June [sic] 3rd, 1986, a team of eight players (six
> finished) played for 66 hours in Ilford, Essex.
>
> A team in Ogden, Utah then got the record for a 1983 game that lasted
> 209 hours.

If you want more information, you should [fill out a general enquiry for Guinness here](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/contact/general-enquiry).

Comment: I would appreciate it if everybody reading this answer took a moment of silence for the poor DM that had to carry on 209 hours.

Comment: For reference: That's 8 days and 17 hours straight.

Comment: I'm really curious what the definition of endurance here is.

Comment: I wonder how much coffee was consumed during that session?

Answer (score 6):

[This thread](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?30175-Current-world-record) suggests that the record was/is 100 hours

> in Dragon issue # 80, pg 54 it states that four members of the Broward Game Players Club in Hollywood FL played D&D for 100 hours straight.

However that was back in 1983, so it might have been broken since then.

Comment: I was there at the Broward county Game Players Club in Hollywood FL for the 100 hour D&D game. All players got 5 min an hour to take care of business. this time could add up after two hours. I cannot remember the D&D modules that were ran.